# Correct arrangement of current sensing resistors for a BLDC motor?

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, current-limiting

I am designing the current limiting (fault detection) circuit for a three phase BLDC motor and I wanted to ask, If I have three switches on at any given time (180 degree commutation) than should the sensing resistors be placed as shown in figure 1, or is it fine to have it as shown in figure 2 which is typically used for 120 degree commutation method. Thank you. [image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure1]

Comment: The lower 3 shud be adequate, and ensure you have >1us dead time to prevent shootthru

Comment: What faults do you want to detect?

Comment: TI has some good app notes on measuring 3phase BLDC motors.  Another common method is to put sense resistors in series with L1 and L2.  Then you can always measure current, even when recirculating.

Comment: I want to limit the current so that I can protect the FETs  from heating up too much

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to check the current limit, then this is the way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCRryv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I want to protect the FETs from overcurrent and I have three of them on at any given time

Comment: @DanielBashy At any time only two transistors conduct, one upper and one lower. So with a single shunt you fully cover the requirement.

Comment: Not for 180 degree commutation you can have three on at any time, 2 from the high side and one from the bottom or vice versa. This way you get more torque out the motor. My question is thay I want to protect the FETs from overcurrent so what is the best arrangement.

Comment: @DanielBashy I see. What is 180 deg. commutation? Never seen, do you have any link?

Comment: Yeah here is the link https://www.academia.edu/5295957/180_degree_commutation_system_of_permanent_magnet_brushless_dc_motor_drive_based_on_speed_and_current_control

Comment: @DanielBashy Still, you can use the same approach, since the current sum flows through a single transistor (2 upper + 1 lower OR 1 upper + 2 lower), so it may not exceed the max. current of a single transistor.